# can't add vpn .ovpn file in network manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect to a vpn using a .ovpn config file. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

```
:~$ openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  5 2019
```

I have been given these instructions to follow:

```
a) Press the Windows key, type settings, click on settings
b) Navigate to "Networking"
c) You should see a "VPN" section on the right
d) Click the "+" next to VPN
e) Select "Import from file..."
f) Once imported enter your LDAP username and password in the "Authentication" section
g) Click the "Add" button in the top right
h) You should now be able to turn the VPN on with the slider next to it's name, it may pop up asking for your password.
i) If connected successfully you will see a new icon in your tray
```

I get to step (g) and the 'add vpn' window closes, but when I go back to the networking/vpn tab, the vpn hasn't appeared (it's as though it has reset itself).

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Please let me know if I can give any more information to help.

My config file is as follows:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote-random
connect-timeout 10
explicit-exit-notify 2
remote **.***.***.*** **** udp
remote **.***.***.*** **** udp
remote vpn-01.***********.co.uk 1199 udp
remote vpn-02.***********.co.uk 1199 udp
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
reneg-sec 86400
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo adaptive
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
verb 4

ca   [inline]
cert [inline]
key  [inline]
```

Comment: can you .ovpn paste your config here? replacing sensitive details with dummy data ofc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used 20.04 to do the same thing recently without any issues so I don't really have an answer but a possible workaround - you could try running the `nm-connection-editor` tool via the command line. I discovered this recently and there are some settings there that are not possible in the standard Ubuntu settings app.

So if there is an issue with the Ubuntu network settings app the tool may not have the same issue.

I have spotted other problems with the ubuntu network settings app - I cannot delete static routes via the app, the window just goes white as if the GUI has crashed. I have to delete them manually by editing files.

Comment: thanks, this worked. this interface seems a lot less buggy than the standard gnome network browser

Answer (score 0):

I never use Network Manager to connect through VPN, command line is much more simple.
For example:

```bsh
$ sudo openvpn sg-sng.prod.com_udp.ovpn
```